# Does Ruby have right operators similar to Python?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

Python [defines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) left and right operators using methods `__radd__`, `__rsub__`, etc.

Does Ruby have something similar?

```
class N32
  def +( other )
    2
  end
end
a = N32.new
a + 3 # return 2
3 + a # return error N32 can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Comment: Uhhh... I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class needs a `coerce` method for this to work:

```
class N32

  def +( other )
    2
  end 

  def coerce(other)
    [self, other]
  end

end

a = N32.new
a + 3 # return 2
3 + a # return 2
```